# Does LoginRequiredMixin Allow Two Forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I downloaded a cookie-cutter django application that provides some basic user handling pages/views.  Typically, login and sign-up pages are separated.  This allows for one {{ form }} to be displayed for each.  I want to place both forms on the same page.  On the front-end, both forms are present with csrf tokens, but submitting the login form POSTs to the sign-up page.  I don't know much about the internals of LoginRequiredMixin (and they are hard to find), but I'm assuming that the {{ form }} that it seems to put on the page is limited to one form.  Is there a way to allow for the submission of two different forms on the same page/view using this mixin?

I assume that this mixin is the issue because the urls it redirects to and the form it mentions are nowhere else in my project code (including urls.py).  If I'm assuming wrong, I'm definitely interested in where the real problem lies.  Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
<div class="forms">     
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="signup">
    <form id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label class="signup-label" for="chk" aria-hidden="true">Sign up</label>
      {{ form }}
      {% if redirect_field_value %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
      {% endif %}
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="login-form">
    <form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label class="login-label" for="chk" aria-hidden="true">Log In</label>
      <!--{{ form }}-->
      <tr>
        <th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username" minlength="1" maxlength="150" required id="id_login">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th>
        <td>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required id="id_password">
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% if redirect_field_value %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
      {% endif %}
      <a class="button secondaryAction" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}" style="margin-left:110px">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a>
      <button class="primaryAction btn btn-primary" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You may configure where `login_required` / `LoginRequiredMixin` will redirects to. Try to set `LOGIN_URL` variable in settings, providing url for your custom view with 2 forms.

Comment: It ended up that both forms were working on the page I had, but the login wouldn't complete because of email verification failure.